# publicar proyecto Laravel 7.5.2 en hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting

Trato de publicar un proyecto Laravel en hosting, dicho proyecto funciona perfectamente en local pero cuando trato de publicarlo me da el siguiente error.

**There is no existing directory at "/home/vagrant/code/Amigosurf/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied**

Tengo todo el proyecto subido en la carpeta "Amigosurf" salvo la carpeta "public" de local que la he publicado en "public_html". 
La base de datos la he importado con phpmyadmin y he realizado los cambios en /home/amigosur/public_html/index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../Amigosurf/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../Amigosurf/bootstrap/app.php';
```

También he añadido a función en el archivo /home/amigosur/public_html/index.php

```
public function register()
{
    //
     $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){
        return'/home/amigosur/public_html';
    });
}
```

En el archivo env. he cambiado con respecto a local enl nombre de la base de datos, el nombre de usuario y la contraseña ahora es el que me han pasado desde el Hosting.

Por último estoy utilizando laravel 7.5.2 y la version de php del hosting es 7.4

Comment: ¿Le diste sus respectivos permisos 755 a las carpetas y 644 a los archivos?

Comment: `mkdir -p -m 775 /home/vagrant/code/Amigosurf/storage/logs`. Posiblemente también `sudo chgrp www-data /home/vagrant/code/Amigosurf/storage/logs`